# how to get data between td tags in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I want to get data between td tags in unix shell script in a generalize way.

for example in the following

```
<td style="padding:3px;" align="center">123.456</td>
```

how to retrieve 123.456 in a generalize way.

Thanks

Comment: In order to help you, can you post What have tried so far?

Comment: What system are you working with? Can you start/install XML Shell (`xmlsh`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with sed,

```
sat:~# cat file
<td style="padding:3px;" align="center">123.456</td>
<td>sat</td>
sat:~#  
sat:~# sed 's/<td\(.*[^<>]\+\?>\)\(.*\)<\/td>/\2/g' file
123.456
sat
sat:~#
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^.*<td.*>\(.*\)<.*$/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

For a proper solution and in a generalized way use a proper parser like [html-xml-utils](http://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/)

for a non-proper and non-gerneralized way, use sed

```
sed 's/^.*>\([0-9.]*\)<.*$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you cannot use a xml parser,

grep was born to extract things. :)

```
grep -Po '(?<=>)[^<]*'
```